# Unity navMeshAgent not working on terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, terrain

The Unity Navmeshagent is not working **!on terrain!**. I'm very kinda new to unity and need help with the navmesh agent.

It's baking fine just that the entity or slender man is not moving. It's actually in the inspector but it's only like 0.0001 per second. Bake and navmesh agent settings are the photos.

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class enemymovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private NavMeshAgent nma;
    public Transform player;
    private void Awake()
    {
        nma = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        StartCoroutine("followpath");
    }

    private IEnumerator followpath()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            nma.SetDestination(player.position);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `nma.SetDestination(player.position)`

And don't put this in an update because it means that your agent will try to calculate a new path in every frame. I suggest using a Coroutine that will call SetDestination from time to time instead of every update.

Comment: I tried doing what you said and nothing happened. I think it may be something else. If you would somehow know how to fix this a reply would be nice. Thanks, new code just look at post.

Comment: Depending on the size of your terrain, maybe 0.1s isnt long enough to calculate and yet you ask to calculate a new one before it was even ready. Let's simply try to set a single destination in the start before using a coroutine. Set one single destination and wait a couple seconds. If that does not work, there is a problem somewhere else. Is the script on the character? Is the NavMeshAgent speed set to 0? Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working. But now the enemy stops every 2 seconds and by changing the value higher it will never catch the player. is there a way to somehow do something about it? Yes, it's a huge map. The player starts at 0, 0, 0 and slender man at 300, 0, -400

Comment: Wait I don't think that will be needed cause the player won't see the enemy soooo far away.

Comment: On a terrain, there is a million different paths an agent can take. By calling SetDestination, Unity has to find the quickest (ish) of them all. You could change the speed at wich the SetDestination is called the closer the agent gets to the player. The closer you are from your target, the less paths there is to calculate, the quicker the pathfinding is.